# React/MUI dark mode switch in child Layout component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, themes, state

In React+MUI (JS), I'm trying to implement a dark mode switch in a **layout** component, but can't find any workaround with states. The objective would be to switch between modes within the switch rendered in the Layout. You'll find here my App.js (with router and layout) and my Layout.js

```
// App.js (incl. routes and react-router-dom)    
const [ darkMode, setDarkMode ] = useState(false)

const theme = createMuiTheme({
   palette: {
    type: darkMode ? "dark" : "light" ,
   }
})

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
//...components
    <Layout {...darkMode}>
    //... other components
```

And then for the Layout component :

```
const Layout = (props) => {

const [ darkMode, setDarkMode ] = React.useState(props.darkMode)
useEffect(() => {
    setDarkMode(props.darkMode)
}, [props.darkMode])

const theme = useTheme()
...
<Switch checked={darkMode} onChange={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} />
...
{props.children}
```

Any help will be delightful, for nothing actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```js
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  createMuiTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@material-ui/core";

const rootTheme = (darkMode) => ({
  palette: {
    type: darkMode ? "dark" : "light"
  }
});

const App = () => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(true);
  const theme = useMemo(() => createMuiTheme(rootTheme(darkMode)), [darkMode]);

  const onClick = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button onClick={onClick}>Change Theme</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```